# Java Regex CodeTitle

Tags: java, regex

I need a "Java RegEx" on title of an html tag, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
Pattern.compile("\\<td class=\"codeTitle\">(.*)\\</td>");

Matcher m = p.matcher("<td class="codeTitle">Java RegEx</td>");
```

Comment: What does not work? To get the value of `(.*)`, you'll need to use the  [`Matcher.group()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)).

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<title>(.*)\\</title>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<title>Java RegEx</title>");
this code work but when i use;
Pattern.compile("\\<td class=\"codeTitle\">(.*)\\</td>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<td class="codeTitle">Java RegEx</td>");
not work :s

Comment: Make some effort to clear out what *exactly* does not work, why it doesn't and what you'd expect it to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `m.find()` to check if it any matches are found. If there are matches found, you can access them using `m.group(1)`.

Moreover, I think you forgot to escape the subject string.

```
Pattern.compile("<td class=\"codeTitle\">(.*?)</td>"); //lazy matching is better in matching html tags

Matcher m = p.matcher("<td class=\"codeTitle\">Java RegEx</td>"); // you didn't escape that

if(m.find()){
  //do something with m.group(1) which contains "Java Regex"
}
else {
  //no matches found
}
```